# Pattern Match Generic Return Type

Tags: generics, scala, pattern-matching, return-type

**EDIT**
Leaving this for posterity, but nearly a year later, to get down voted, nice...would not do anything like the below now, but at the time, getting started with Scala, questions generally come from a place of ignorance....

**ORIGINAL**
I know I can just wrap a pattern match in a method with generic type specified like so:

```
def getTeam[T <: _Team](clazz: String): _Team =
  clazz match {
    case "roster" => new RosterController
    case "schedule" => new ScheduleController
  }
```

and get a meaningful type (_Team) for the compiler to work with.

However, I am wondering if it is possible to do this WITHOUT a wrapper method and without asInstanceOf[_Team] boilerplate? i.e. something other than

```
clazz match {
  case "roster" => new RosterController.asInstanceOf[_Team]
  case "schedule" => new ScheduleController.asInstanceOf[_Team]
}
```

Not the end of the world if not possible, but would prefer to do the matches in place vs. splitting into a separate method.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to cast? A `RosterController` either is an instance of `_Team` or it is not. A cast is not going to do you any good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you think is going on in this method but it seems like you are either confused or have written the wrong thing down.

In your example, `T` is a type parameter, bounded above by the type `_Team` (which I assume is either a class or a trait). You subsequently ignore `T`, so it *could* be a *phantom* type but from your question, but it doesn't really seem like it.

You **cannot possibly** need to cast `RosterController` into a `_Team` because it either is one or it isn't. I can infer this because `RosterController` must be a concrete class as you are instantiating it. It's either a subtype of `_Team` or it is not.

If `_Team` is a trait, it can be mixed in:

```
new RosterController with _Team
```

But because you don't explain what you are trying to actually do, it's difficult to say for sure! Is `RosterController` also parameterized?

---

**EDIT** - from the comments below, it seems that you are wondering about what the compiler infers as the result type of an expression where that expression is a `match` statement.

Here's a useful example as to how the compiler can infer really quite a lot of cool stuff

```
scala> class Bar; class Baz; trait Foo
defined class Bar
defined class Baz
defined trait Baz
```

Now let's create a match expression:

```
scala> def foo(s: String) = s match {
   | case "a" => new Baz with Foo
   | case _   => new Bar with Foo
   | }
foo: (s: String)ScalaObject with Foo
```

So the compiler has correctly inferred `Foo` here. Perhaps you could rephrase your question, distilling in a **REPL example** exactly what you expect and how that differs from what actually happens.

Comment: The question states WITHOUT a wrapper method; i.e the first example uses a wrapper method with return type specified.  I am asking about a standalone match block against string class name that could return different controller instances which have a common super type. "with _Team" does work; without that, compiler views result of the match as generic scala object, which I can't do much with ;-) Thanks

Comment: But you did not state that `_Team` was a trait and that you wanted to mix it in. The cast simply would not have worked (it wouldn't even have compiled)

Comment: Right, previously I was using a _Controller super class. So had new RosterController.asInstanceOf[_Controller] which did compile. I guess the point is that you have to provide a common type for a match block; if not, it seems you have to wrap the match in a method with return type specified.

Comment: Also, the _Team trait is already mixed in to RosterController in class definition itself.  Regardless, the compiler cannot infer the returned type in match block without using "with _Team" or wrapping match in a method with return type specified.

Comment: I really think that you should re-ask the question because, as it stands, it doesn't express what you are trying to find out. A `match` expression in scala (as with any other expression) has a type. The compiler should be able to infer a type from the common supertypes of the `case` statements. I'm going to append to my answer an example

Comment: ...and neither the question, nor any of your comments have suggested that any of this has *anything* to do with generics!

Comment: right, just trying to get around specifying "with _Team" on each matched case. "class RosterController extends _Controller with _Team", I guess the compiler cannot infer common super type, one must tell the compiler explicitly

Comment: The compiler can infer common supertype and lots more. That is why I suggested you distil an example in the Repl

Comment: here's what I've been trying to do all along: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052879/invoking-anonymous-closure" can probably close this question as the 2 are related

Answer (score 1):

> trait _Team{ def doWhat_TeamCanDo(s:String){println s} }

```
class MyTeamString(clazz: String)

 implicit def getTeam: _Team =
  clazz match {
    case "roster" => new RosterController with _Team
    case "schedule" => new ScheduleController with _Team
 }
}

implicit def strToMyTeamString(s:String):MyTeamString= MyTeamString(s)
```

now you can "convert" any string to a _Team when you need it, implicitly:

```
"roster".doWhat_TeamCanDo("foo")
```

Comment: interesting, that is a nice way to hide away the implementation.  However, I don't mind being explicit in this case, as controller instantiation occurs here in the routing layer.